# Name of protocol used to communicate with Fuelling Station Dispensors

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, automotive-engineering, microelectronics

I am trying to figure out the actual (Range of ) communication protocols used to communicate with Fuel Dispensers at fuel retail outlets.

I see them write 2-wire protocol which is not specific as there are a bunch of communication protocols that communicate over 2 wires. I am suspecting it to be CAN but not sure.

I will be glad if anyone can assist with even further information on communication with fuel station devices

Comment: Who makes the pumps used at the station? Veeder Root? Do you think they have a proprietry comms system?

Comment: @SolarMike A few of the dispensors i want to target are manufactured by VEEDER ROOT which is what i actually want to start with. Yes, i read veeder root have a proprietry protocol, but i assumed the physical layer of the protocol will be a standard industry interface.